# connecting java application with online hosted mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans-7

I have build an application in java, application is one and will be used on 3 different systems,
And therefore the database of that application must be online to keep all 3 applications with up to date database...

In starting I developed my application based on localhost (wampserver) and used database in "PhpMyAdmin", and hopefully application is fully developed and ready to run.. but the problem is online database connectivity! 
I have uploaded my database on a [Site](http://www.biz.nf/) in PhpMyAdmin and they provided below information:
[image]

and the for connecting my app to this DB is:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://fdb12.biz.nf:3306/";
String dbName = "1738412_wstore";

String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "1738412_wstore"; 
String password = "Password";  

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
```

now when I run my application it shows below error:
[image]

I dont know what the problem is there, please help me out through this..

Comment: Your server host probably does not allow 3rd party hosts to connect to their database instances. You'll need a dedicated (or virtual private) server *that you can control* for this.

Comment: See if the user `1738412_wstore` has permission to external access. In the mysql database you query the user table and see the value of the column HOST if it is localhost or 127.0.0.1 That means that this user cannot access from outside. It should be `%`

Comment: in the commande-line type : telnet YOUR_REMOTE_SERVER 3306 , if you don"t get a black sceen than the db server doesn't allow remote connection

Comment: its showing connection error while in command line typing Telnet fdb12.biz.nf 3306

Comment: @JorgeCampos how to allow database so that it can be accessed... and how can I change value of HOST from localhost to %

Comment: I didn't realize that it was a external site. So you probably have to make contact with your service provider and ask then to give you remote access to your database. There's nothing more to do besides that.

Comment: any other source for online DB hosting ??? which can give me access ??

Comment: @Rafi, see my answer. You can use heroku, as I said. Don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and the following helped me to solve.

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database-remotely

Hopefully, your hosting provider should have same type of cpanel to configure MySQL database for remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for firewall.
2. Check if mysql is running.

Comment: please can you guide me how to check for firewall and mysql running...?? coz this is the first time im working with mysql

Comment: Check for port no 3306 . which default port on which mysql runs. Check if that port is open.

Comment: If linux then (service mysql status) will give you running status. For port (netstat -nap)

Comment: Check in task manager is mysql service is running. And for port try netstat -a

Comment: Is mysql server in local mechine? Also check for the user authorization in mysql .

Comment: netstat -a
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             RafiAbro-PC:0          LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            RafiAbro-PC:0          LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            RafiAbro-PC:0          LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            RafiAbro-PC:0          LISTENING

Comment: I have uploaded database on site.. web hosting site with phpmyadmin.. I want to connect my app to that online DB

Comment: there is an entry for 3306:
TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           RafiAbro-PC:0          LISTENING

Comment: Then problem with the user i believe.

Comment: and what is the solution for that?

Comment: Grant proper privilege to the user. And also check if you are able to connect to mysql with that user in CLI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63124/discussion-between-user4087819-and-rafi-abro).

Comment: use telnet command from the command prompt, to verify the port is open and accessible from your location: telnet fdb12.biz.nf 3306

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can try:

1. Install MySql client locally on your machine and connect like: `mysql -h fdb12.biz.nf -u 1738412_wstore -P<password>`

This should work before you try anything else.

2. Make sure you're using the right imports in your code. See [here][1].

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.SQLException;

Answer (score 0):

I think your DB server doesn't allow remote connections.

Try hosting in:

http://www.freesqldatabase.com/freemysqldatabase/

It's free and allow remote DB connections.

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the *Biz.nf* FAQ:

> **How can I connect to my MySQL/PostgreSQL database? What settings
> should I use for my script/software?**
>
> MySQL/PosgreSQL database connection can be established with script/software hosted only on your
> web hosting account (meaning no remote access is allowed due to
> security reasons). The following settings are needed:

So, since *biz.nf* does not allow remote access, it will be difficult for you to interact with their MYSQL server for your application.

The best solution and the most simple is probably to find a new provider which will allow the remote access. [Heroku.com](http://heroku.com) works very well.

If you really want to use the *biz.nf* services, it will be more difficult.

It's not a script or credential problem.

Maybe you can (probably not), try to login by SSH to configure your server to enable remote access to your MYSQL database server.

From the free plan, you will not have any access to the online SSH tool and you will need to configure your domain for a SSH connection.

In SSH, and it probably will not work considering the FAQ, you could try to simply modify your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file by commenting the `bind-address` line wich by default only allows local access (127.0.0.1). Then, try to restart your MYSQL service with: a simple `service mysql restart` to verify if the remote connection works.

If the remote connection still doesn't work after this, the only way I can find for the moment (unless you completely change your hosting provider) would be to create a kind of `API` hosted directly on the server and your Java program could interacts with your services (In JSON, by example).