# is it possible to connect java application to online database

Tags: java, mysql

hello i am trying to connect my application to online database using the following code

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class javacon {
    Connection con = null;

    private static final String url ="jdbc:mysql:\\sql204.byethost9.com:3306\\";
    private static final String dbName = "b9_16134488_db";
    private static final String userName = "b9_16134488";
    private static final String password = "123.321";

    public static Connection connectDB(){
    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql204.byethost9.com:3306/b9_16134488_db/",userName,password);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connection is succseful");
      return con;
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    return null;
    }


    }
}
```

> but i am getting error says the driver has not received any packet
>   from the server

i found one answer  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389011/connecting-java-application-with-online-hosted-mysql-database) says i have to go to my cpanel in my host and add my ip address there but i need every user to be connect to the database to login and logout

Comment: Yes, but it's unrecommended. Does the database allow connections from an external ip?

Comment: *"says i have to add my ip address but i need all user to connect to the database not only the one i add"* I'm sorry, what? Do you have lots of databases on different servers?

Comment: i don't really know but i think no it is not because i am trying and it is not working

Comment: @MadProgrammer why it is unrecommended? - my own personal curiosity. What would be the recommended way of connecting a database to a java application?

Comment: Did you just post real credentials to your database?

Comment: yes i don't care about the host it's free for experiment

Comment: @MadProgrammer is my code correct no wrong with it

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I disagree, he didn't say public database, but having database as separated server is quite common. Then you must be careful about setup of DB (access rights) and setup of server and access to it.

Comment: It's unrecommended because you are exposing your database to potential hacking. It's unrecommended because know you seem to be placing the business logic for the application on the client side, which becomes difficult to update should it change (which is generally does), rather then relying on a access layer which all clients must go through. It's unrecommended because you'd have to either store the login credentials in your application or send them over the wire, further risking the potential risk of hacking. You might be required to provide a user account for each potential user...

Comment: @Skube Accessing a Database directly from a client is unrecommended, and should, where possible be done via a service layer, the service layer may then be required to connect to a private network to access the database, which is a more preferable solution as it centralises the access point, centralises the business logic, allows for internal configuration changes which don't mean the clients need to be changed, reduces user configuration to the database and improves security...:P

Comment: @BigRabbit I don't use MySQL that much, but the trailing "/" after the database name looks wrong to me (based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html))

Comment: `String url ="jdbc:mysql:\\sql204.byethost9.com:3306\\";` Get rid of this. It isn't valid, and you aren't using it.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql database has file `my.cnf` where `bind-address` might be specified. If that is not there, then mysql bind itself to all interfaces, otherwise only to specified one. More about this [Bind-address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address)

Also I guess user must have permissions to connect to database. `'user'@'ipaddress'`. And more you can read here [Connection access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html)

Comment: where i can find the file my.cnf

Comment: On Linux `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` what I assume you are using. EDIT: I hope you understand that that is on the server where you online database is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, your problem probably is related with your MySQL database not allowing connections from your host. The easiest way to find if this is the problem is trying to connect to the database from the same machine with the same credentials with [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

There are three main things that can block your MySQL from receiving external connections:

**1) Configuration**

Edit my.cnf removing the following line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

**2) User Host**

In MySQL all users have defined from which host the connection can home from. 'user'@'%' would allow you to connect from any host.

**3) Firewall**

Make sure that the port 3306 is open.